# How can I convert a array with repeat value to hash in ruby?

Tags: ruby

What is the easiest way to do the following conversion.

```
[#Obj<name: "a", value: 1>, #Obj<name: "a", value: 2>, #Obj<name: "a", value: 3>, #Obj<name: "b", value: 1>, #Obj<name: "b", value: 2>]
```

=>

```
{
 "a"=> [1, 2, 3],
 "b"=> [1, 2]
}
```

Comment: Your inner hash are not valid hash syntax.. to make it valid use `=>` instead of `:`...

Comment: @ArupRakshit That's why my question get downvoted? :(

Comment: Odds are good the question is getting down-votes because you're not providing valid input, nor showing any effort you put into solving the problem. As a result it's difficult to help you without coercing your "data" into something usable. You have to help the answerers help you.

Comment: The reason of down vote, I don't know friend.. sorry :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps using [`inject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) to process the list. The methods `inject` and `reduce` are equivalent (one is the alias of the other).

```
hash = my_arr.inject({}) do |h, o|
  (h[o.name] ||= []) << o.value
  h
end
```

This should give you the results you're looking for.

Comment: write as `(h[o.name] ||= []) << o.value`. Then no need local variable `arr`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
array = [#Obj<name: "a", value: 1>, #Obj<name: "a", value: 2>, #Obj<name: "a", value: 3>, #Obj<name: "b", value: 1>, #Obj<name: "b", value: 2>]

hash = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = []}

array.each {|e| hash[e.name] << e.value}
```

Alternatively, if you like loops:

```
for e in array
  (h ||= Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = [] })[e.name] << e.value
end
```

Comment: Why on earth would you use a `for` loop? Use an iteration method like `each` or a more functional one like `reduce`/`inject` over a for loop for this kind of thing.

Comment: Oh come now. I would have thought that two fine commenters with high reps such as yourselves would know that the *whole* point behind the expressiveness of Ruby is that there are multiple ways of doing the same thing. Since both of you already used `inject/reduce` I decided to show something else. If you want the method using an iterator, by all means use either of yours or my own `each` implementation

Comment: That is a valid point; however, `for` loops (or "manual" looping) should be avoided unless absolutely necessary in Ruby as a best practice as there are more clear (iterators) alternatives. Also, you bogged down your "alternative" solution by making a not only a "manual" loop recommendation but one-lining it (with semi-colons) which just leads to ugly code in Ruby and shouldn't be promoted in any regard. If you clean that up and span it on the three lines that it should be on I will concede your point on offering "another alternative" but as it stands, I don't think that should be promoted.

Comment: @izuriel fair enough point haha... I do have a soft spot for oneliners. Making the change now.

Comment: You have my apologies for my initial reaction, I've given an upvote for providing yet another alternative solution (again, one of my favorite things about ruby questions). So again, you have my apologies for my initial reaction to your post.

Comment: Not to worry, that's one of my favorite things about Ruby too. I may have been a little jealous that you beat me to the punch with `inject` haha

Answer (score 2):

You can do as below using [`each_with_object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) :

```
arry.each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }) do |ob,hash|
  hash[ob.name] << ob.value
end
```

Comment: I didn't know about `each_with_object`, I love Ruby questions because everyone usually does things their own way. I also didn't think about the Hash creation with a block. +1

Comment: I think each_with_object is much better. #inject / #reduce as far as my experience goes is better warranted for when the object being used is immutable like a numeric object (e.g. [1,2,3].inject(:+) # where the object is the default 0 Fixnum)

Comment: I would accept this answer too if I can accept multiple

Comment: I don't think I agree, ultimately this works in a similar way as `each_with_object`, the only real difference is the return value from the block for `inject`/`reduce` where as `each_with_object` returns the original object given (the difference being not dependent on the blocks return value). That makes this solution "cleaner" as there is no trailing reference to the hash for the memo, but other than that I don't think that means that `inject`/`reduce` is only for immutable values.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Enumerable#reduce`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce). E.g. if `arr` is your array:

```
arr.reduce(Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = []}) do |hash, obj|
    hash[obj.name] << obj.value
    hash
end
```